# Java instrumentation tools for bytecode analysis? (intercepting java webapp bytecode during loadtime)

Tags: java, web-applications, bytecode, instrumentation, exploit

I'll start with presenting my motivation: i am researcher , and i am working on few ideas to prevent java webapp exploits (till now worked with windbg and other tools for non-java type of exploits) .

I am interested to intercept java webapp loading, analize it's bytecode, and optionally hook some of it's methods (client side).

1. I assume it is possible by extending the class loader.
2. I assume the hooking and analyzation is possible by using agent instrumentation.

My question is more focusing on best practices , and for those who already expirienced or done some java webapp varification during runtime.

- So what tools i should use to intercept and debug the bytecode of the java webapp?
- What framework should i use to write my instrumentation?
- What editing tool is best for this porposes, eclipse, IDE, others?
- Do you have any guidlines / links to open source project with similar intentions?

Comment: I'd look at AspectJ first.

Comment: Have you checked existing solutions in this space? SonarQube has some security related inspections.  FindBug may give an idea about class parsing and analyzing.

Comment: 1+ for research that you are doing

Comment: Look at http://asm.ow2.org/